# Restart the audio from where it had stopped when the audio played after clicking a button finishes

Tags: android, audio

I am playing an audio (mySound) as background music. On clicking a button, the background audio should stop and a different audio (mySound11) should start playing. After this audio gets done, the background music should automatically resume from where it had left. I have tried this code, but the background audio doesn't resume after mySound11 is over. Please help. Thanks in advance.

### **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    MediaPlayer mySound;
    MediaPlayer mySound11;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mySound11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tiktik);
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jhakmaarke);
        mySound.setLooping(true);
        mySound.start();

    }



        public void playMusic (View view){
            mySound.pause();
            mySound11.start();
        }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mySound.start();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mySound.release();
        mySound11.release();
        finish();
    }
```

---

### **activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button Dabaa be"
    android:onClick="playMusic"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved your problem with the help of Thread.
I tested it working as you wished.

```
int mySound11Duration;
MediaPlayer mySound;
MediaPlayer mySound11;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySound11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tiktik);
    mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jhakmaarke);
    mySound.setLooping(true);
    mySound.start();

}
 public void playMusic(View view) {
        if (mySound.isPlaying()) { //check mysound is playing or not
            mySound11Duration = mySound11.getDuration();
            Thread thread=new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mySound.pause();
                        int mySoundPausePosition = mySound.getCurrentPosition();//get the time where the song is paused.
                        mySound11.start();
                        sleep(mySound11Duration);//sleep method causes the currently executing thread to sleep for specified number of time(miliseconds). 
                        mySound.seekTo(mySoundPausePosition);
                        mySound.start();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi you have not told me that your problem is solved or not.